# How would I take the number of names in a list and then write the results to a file?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and am having difficulties with this (most likely simple) problem. I'm accepting a file with the format.

```
name_of_sports_team    year_they_won_championship
```

e.g.,

```
1991    Minnesota
1992    Toronto
1993    Toronto
```

They are already separated into a nested list [year][name]. I am tasked to add up all the repetitions from the list and display them as such in a new file.

```
Toronto    2 
Minnesota    1
```

My code is as follows-

```
def write_tab_seperated(n):
    '''
    N is the filename
    '''

    file = open(n, "w")

    # names are always in the second position?
    data[2] = names

    countnames = () 
    # counting the names 
    for x in names:
    # make sure they are all the same    
    x = str(name).lower()
        # add one if it shows. 
        if x in countnames:
            countnames[x] += 1
        else:
            countnames[x] = 1
    # finish writing the file 
    file.close
```

This is so wrong its funny, but I planned out where to go from here:

- Take the file
- separate into the names list
- add 1 for each repetition
- display in name(tab)number format
- close the file.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: hey @Speter, do you want to restructure the code or leave it as similar as possible?

Comment: @PeterDolan I have no preference, seeing that there is a good chance I am going down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: I added an example using python's counter datatype which is really useful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand through your explanation, the following is my piece of code:

```
#input.txt is the input file with <year><tab><city> data
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    input_list =[x.strip().split('\t') for x in f]

output_dict = {}
for per_item in input_list:
    if per_item[1] in output_dict:
        output_dict[per_item[1]] += 1
    else:
        output_dict[per_item[1]] = 1

#output file has <city><tab><number of occurence>
file_output = open("output.txt","w")
for per_val in output_dict:
    file_output.write(per_val + "\t" + str(output_dict[per_val]) + "\n")
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in datatype that's perfect for your use case called [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

I'm assuming from the sample I/O formatting that your data file columns are tab separated.  In the question text it looks like 4-spaces — if that's the case, just change `'\t'` to `'    '` or `' '*4` below.

```
with open('data.tsv') as f:
    lines = (l.strip().split('\t') for l in f.readlines())
```

Once you've read the data in, it really is as simple as passing it to a Counter and specifying that it should create counts on the values in the second column.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(x[1] for x in lines)
```

And printing them back out for reference:

```
for k, v in c.items():
    print('{}\t{}'.format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
Minnesota   1
Toronto 2
```

Comment: great answer. nitpicking, but how about `for l in f.read().strip().split('\n')` -> `for l in f.readlines() if l`

Comment: The one caveat that gets me with `readlines()` is that it leaves the trailing `\n` on each line, but yeah overall, that's a bit cleaner — I just updated it to use that, and also replaced the list comprehensions with generators.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about python is the huge number of packages. For handling tabular data, I'd recommend using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) and the [`csv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format:

```
import pandas as pd

years = list(range(1990, 1994))
names = ['Toronto', 'Minnesota', 'Boston', 'Toronto']

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data={'years': years, 'names': names})

dataframe.to_csv('path/to/file.csv')
```

That being said, I would still highly recommend to go through your code and learn how these things are done from scratch.

Comment: i'm not sure this answers the question - doesn't the OP want to read data from disk and inspect it? You're snippet writes data to disk.

Comment: His function is called `write_tab_seperated()`, so I'm fairly sure he wants to write.